# Verify which character I have in my string in assembly NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I need to do a validation to check if the string that I got from the user starts with capital letter and ends with period.
How do I check that? I think my biggest problem is how do I know that I am in the last letter of my string?

Thank you

That's what I have so far:
My r8 is holding my string and size is holding the string size + null character.
I know this is wrong because I am getting
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

```
validate:
        mov rcx, [size]
        sub rcx, 1
        movzx edi, byte [r8+ rcx]

        cmp 46, [edi] ;46 is period in the ascii table
        je choice3
        jne exit
        ret
```

Comment: What is your string convention? Do you know the length, or is it zero terminated? In either case, you know where the last character should be. And you ost certainly know where it starts, so what is your problem?

Comment: @Devolus I don't understand. If I knew what my last character was I would not have done this post. My questions is I got a string from the user how do I validate if the last character is a period. So far I did a function to get my string size, but I am still having problems to check if the last character is a period. So let's say r8 is holding my string and rcx is holding the size, what I have now is - and I know  is wrong - cmp 2E, byte [r8+ rcx]

Comment: You load the last byte into `edi`, but then you derefence it as if it were a pointer. Since it is only a byte you can do a simple `mov ebl, byte[r8*rcx]`and then compare `bl` against `.`.

Comment: @Devolus I get error that . is undefined. I think I should be comparing with the ascII table. Any other idea?

Comment: `cmp 2E, byte [r8+ rcx]` would work except that hex constants need a `0x` prefix, so `cmp 0x2E, byte [r8+rcx]`.  There's a typo in @Devolus's suggestion, should be `mov bl, byte [r8+rcx]` and then that would also work.

Comment: @NateEldredge when I try doing cmp 0x2E, byte [r8+rcx] I get error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: Oh sorry, I've got them switched.  The immediate operand goes second.  Make it `cmp byte [r8+rcx], 0x2E`.

Comment: And what you have would have worked if you wrote `cmp edi, 46`.

Comment: @NateEldredge so I do not get the error anymore. But when it compares it does not show like they are equal even though it should be. How can I see what edi is holding? Trying to run gdb but I am not understand what I am seeing

Comment: `p $edi` shows you what is in `edi`.  There might be a problem with the way you are setting `size`, so if you need more help, I suggest creating a [mcve].

Comment: @NateEldredge it shows the following (gdb) p$edi $1 = 10. Also my size shows 7 which is correct because my string is Hello. x/d &size 0x40418c <size>:        7

Comment: Ah, so you are off by one.  If `size` is 7 then the null byte is at `[r8+6]` and the period is at `[r8+5]`.  So you ought to have `sub rcx, 2`.  (Or drop the `sub` and do `cmp [r8+rcx-2], 0x2e`.)

Comment: @NateEldredge it's working now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Devolus: You mean `cmp dil, '.'`.  The quotes are important when you want the numeric value / ASCII code of a character.  Also, `ebl` isn't a register.    I guess you meant `movzx` into EBX, then compare `bl`, but `ecx`, `eax`, or `edx` would be better choices (call-clobbered registers like `edi`, in x86-64 SysV).

Answer (score 3):

So there were three bugs:

- Off-by-one: since indices start at 0, then if `size` counts the number of bytes including the null, the null itself is at `[r8+size-1]` and the final non-null character is at `[r8+size-2]`.  So your `sub rcx, 1` should be `sub rcx, 2`.  (Make sure you have a test somewhere else that the string is not empty.)
- Register vs memory operand: Using `[edi]` in the `cmp` instruction would be a memory operand: it will use `edi` as an address, and compare the byte in memory at that address.  But here `edi` already contains the value you want, so use it as a register operand, with just `edi` instead of `[edi]`.
- Operand order: In Intel syntax, the immediate operand of `cmp` should be the second operand.  So it should be `cmp edi, 46`.  If you want to use hex, be sure to use a `0x` prefix: `cmp edi, 0x2e`.  But you can also use character constants, so `cmp edi, '.'` also works and is more readable.

Thus in the end you'd have

```
        sub rcx, 2
        movzx edi, byte [r8+ rcx]

        cmp edi, '.'
```

But you can get the desired effect with just one instruction:

```
        cmp byte [r8+rcx-2], '.'
```